# svg file included in MIMEImage is not properly displayed in html email

Tags: python, html, svg, mime-types, mimemultipart

I need to send email with logo file which is svg. I attach it but it does not get displayed correctly.

Here is my code:

```
msg=MIMEMultipart()

img_msg=MIMEMultipart('related')

full_path_to_logo_file=os.path.join('C:\\Users\\emails\\images', 'email-logo.svg')

with open(full_path_to_logo_file, 'rb') as logo_file:

   logo_in_binary=logo_file.read()

logo_image=MIMEImage(logo_in_binary, _subtype="svg")

logo_image.add_header('Content-ID','<logo_image_svg>')

img_msg.attach(logo_image)

full_path_to_background_image_file=os.path.join('C:\\Users\\emails\\images', 'email-background.jpg')

with open(full_path_to_background_image_file, 'rb') as background_image_file:
 background_in_binary=background_image_file.read()

background_image=MIMEImage(background_in_binary, _subtype="jpg")

background_image.add_header('Content-ID','<background_image_jpg>') 

img_msg.attach(background_image)


msg.attach(img_msg)
```

Part with **jpg** image works fine.

Here is how it looks in email.

[image]

**svg** file gets attached to email and when I open it with editor, I see svg-xml paths. So, it looks like it works in terms of data being generated, but somehow it does not get attached to email properly.

Here is html/css code of email:

```
     <!--[if mso]>
     <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="350" align="center">
     <tr>
     <td>
     <![endif]-->
     <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0 auto;">
         <tr>
             <td bgcolor="#000000" style="background-color: #000000; padding: 0 25px;">
                 <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                     <tr>
                         <td style="padding: 10px 0; text-align: center; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF;">
                             <img src="cid:logo_image_svg" width="90" height="50" alt=" " border="0" style="height: auto; background: #000000; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-size: 10px; line-height: 10px; color: #FFFFFF;">
                         </td>
                     </tr>
                 </table>
             </td>
         </tr>
     </table>
     <!--[if mso]>
     </td>
     </tr>
     </table>
     <![endif]-->
 </div>
```

P.S. I have sent this to gmail account.

P.P.S. Another interesting thing is that when I remove **_subtype="svg"**, I am getting error saying that it cannot recognize type of the file. Could this be somehow related?

Comment: Is it a case of the email client simply not supporting it? https://www.caniemail.com/features/image-svg/

Comment: You be might right. I thought that svg is universally supported. I have used gmail to test it.